# unable to remove backslash delimiter from svg file

Tags: c#, xml, string, svg

I want to remove black slash delimiter from below svg file. The delimiter get added when I am extracting xml as string from Web api. With delimiter when I am trying to view the file in the browser I am getting error as

"error on line 1 at column 15: String not started expecting ' or.

I don't know how to remove these delimiter ('') from below SVG. I have tried using string replace and remove functions but I am unable to remove the delimiter. Also, on posting the question below code does not show delimiter. In order to view delimiter we have to save below SVG with .svg extension and then I have used code. In debugger, I can see delimited xml. Please help.

```
string a = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\SVGToJPEG\Buyers_svg.svg");
var k = RemoveNewLine(a);

public static string RemoveNewLine(string str)
{
   str = str.Replace("\n\t\t", "").Replace("\n", "");
   str = str.Replace("\b", "");
   return str;
 }
```

"``` <svg id=\"Layer_1\" data-name=\"Layer 1\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 237.43 244.07\"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#ff0;}.cls-2{fill:#231f20;}.cls-2,.cls-3{stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:8px;}.cls-3{fill:none;}</style></defs><path class=\"cls-1\" d=\"M216,95c0,51.32-40.74,92.92-91,92.92S34,146.29,34,95C34,55.05,61.48,28.31,64.14,25.9c5-4.53,28.3-24.72,60.86-23.84C168.19,3.23,216,41.14,216,95Z\" transform=\"translate(-6.63 -2.03)\"/><path class=\"cls-2\" d=\"M42.26,59.6\" transform=\"translate(-6.63 -2.03)\"/><path class=\"cls-3\" d=\"M11.27,58.38c-4.91.18,19.51-.52,31.14-.84L90.48,171.61,77,206s-2.2,3.19,3.84,3.15l77.36-.5s72.6-.53,66.24-.43\" transform=\"translate(-6.63 -2.03)\"/><path class=\"cls-3\" d=\"M62.91,85.73\" transform=\"translate(-6.63 -2.03)\"/><path class=\"cls-3\" d=\"M77,127.19\" transform=\"translate(-6.63 -2.03)\"/><path class=\"cls-3\" d=\"M90.55,171.28c142.5-11.92,140.6-11.92,140.6-11.92\" transform=\"translate(-6.63 -2.03)\"/><path class=\"cls-3\" d=\"M133,168.42\" transform=\"translate(-6.63 -2.03)\"/><line class=\"cls-3\" x1=\"129.35\" y1=\"85.52\" x2=\"129.35\" y2=\"163.58\"/><line class=\"cls-3\" x1=\"181.81\" y1=\"85.52\" x2=\"182.1\" y2=\"162.33\"/><path class=\"cls-3\" d=\"M70.19,121.73c167.17,1,164.94.79,164.94.79\" transform=\"translate(-6.63 -2.03)\"/><path class=\"cls-3\" d=\"M55.4,86.4c186.57,2.38,176.7,2,184.08,2.19\" transform=\"translate(-6.63 -2.03)\"/><path class=\"cls-3\" d=\"M240.06,84.63c0,1.78-8.62,74.44-8.55,78.3\" transform=\"translate(-6.63 -2.03)\"/><ellipse cx=\"12``3\" cy=\"229.53\" rx=\"14.3\" ry=\"14.54\"/><ellipse cx=\"180.16\" cy=\"229.53\" rx=\"14.3\" ry=\"14.54\"/></svg> ```"

Comment: That's just how C# shows you the string since it contains double quotes that need to be escaped, there are no backslashes in that string.

Comment: I have removed the double quotes below SVG but now the error is : error on line 1 at column 9: AttValue: " or ' expected.

Comment: Double quote is the problem. I have used another Replace("\"", "'"); Thank you so much . Your comments worked for me. Thank you.